# Is there a number that using the rules of Collatz conjecture's variation $3n-1$ doesn't get to $1, 7$ or $17$?

Tags: open-problem, collatz-conjecture

The rules are simple:

Take any number $n$. If $n$ is even divide it by two, if $n$ is odd triple it and subtract one. Repeat indefinitely. (Note that this is a **variation**, in the original [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) you add one.)

Like the original Collatz conjecture seems to always get to one, this variation always seems to get to either $1, 7$ or $17$. I checked that it does for initial values of $n$ up to **443 million**.

Can you give a number that doesn't get to $1$, $7$ or $17$, or if not, at least show that such number exists?

Comment: $\{5,14,7,20,10\}$ is the cycle, and it clearly goes through seven.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX The question is to find a trajectory that **never** passes through 1, 7, or 17.

Comment: @user326210 there was a comment which suggested n = 5 and the comment from AlgorithmsX is an answer to that now deleted comment

Comment: I think mathematics isn't ready for this thing either (borrowing Erdős)... but I do suspect that any Collatz-like iteration has a finite number of cycles. I'm moving on from here.

Comment: It is the same ***open problem*** as the collatz-conjecture itself: nobody knows it whether another cycle exists or not/whether such a number is existent.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms how do you know it's the same problem? Or do you just mean very similar?

Comment: I say this because the structure of the problem is the same. Although because of the different parameter ($-1$ instead of $+1$) we have two additional cycles (besides $1\to1$) I cannot see any algebraical/analytical difference. (In my comment I had the emphasis with "the same" on the fact of "being unsolved", but I think the focus should even better lay on the analytical/algebraical structure as I say it now in this comment).

Comment: Paul Edos says that....Not All mathematicians say that...Mathematics is ready. We are not ready.

Comment: Zero, negative numbers, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function (let's call it $g: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z$) is just $g(x)=-f(-x)$ with $f$ being the normal Collatz function.

Your cycles are known, they correspond to $\{-1\rightarrow-2\}$, $\{-5\rightarrow-14\rightarrow-7\rightarrow-20\rightarrow-10\}$ and $\{-17\rightarrow-50\rightarrow-25\rightarrow-74\rightarrow-37\rightarrow-110\rightarrow-55\rightarrow-164\rightarrow-82\rightarrow-41\rightarrow-122\rightarrow-61\rightarrow-182\rightarrow-91\rightarrow-272\rightarrow-136\rightarrow-68\rightarrow-34\}$ for $f$.

It is unknown whether the Collatz hypothesis is true on the naturals, even less is known about extensions. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Iterating_on_all_integers